# optimize angular filter performance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, dom

I am filtering a fairly small dataset but there is still some performance issues (UI thread freezing when filter is not concise).

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.user" />
    <table class="tbl" ng-show="vm.user.length > 2">
        <tbody ng-repeat="p in vm.permissions | filter: {UserName: vm.user}:false">
```

the issue is only when there are a lot of records, so I've attempted to improve performance by hiding the whole thing when there are less than 3 characters entered in search.

unfortunately, even when the data-set is hidden it appears that angular is manipulating the dom (UI freezing as I type into the filter).

Is there a way to make it not do anything when there are less characters, and/or improve performance in other ways?

Comment: Not sure if this will address your issue, but you'd want to use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` since it would actually remove the element from the DOM as opposed to just hide it with CSS

Comment: yep, that did it. I still think it's odd that the DOM gets manipulated for hidden elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make 3 suggestions to improve performance:

1. As New Dev said, use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` to remove the whole node from the DOM, which will mean that no processing of directives on the removed nodes will occur at all. I tend to prefer `ng-if` in 99% of scenarios now, unless I know that the visibility of the option will toggle a lot and therefore modifying the class of an existing node is quicker than inserting and removing the same node over and over again.
2. Use a `track by` in your `ng-repeat` expression. This means that Angular will re-use DOM nodes for items in the array that have the same matching value. e.g. if you have `track by p.UserName` (so long as UserName is 100% unique), if it encounters a record with the same username, it will use the same DOM node as before, rather than recreating a new one.
3. Use `ng-model-options` to have a *debounce* on the filter input so that if a user is typing fast, not every keystroke will trigger a new filtering operation. You may need to experiment to find the correct timeout value that works for you in your target browsers.

I have created an [example Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SNmSePgP6Jh0SPyWFRHu?p=preview) that shows these techniques in action. When I tried it with 100,000 records in the list of "permissions" (really just dummy users in the example), it was still very fast in Chrome. Didn't test in other browsers, though.